# Unable to rename Internal Storage files programmatically in Android 9 and 10

Tags: java, android, rename

I am building an application which has a function that renames a file in the Internal Storage.

The code:

```
  Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            File currentFile = new File("/sdcard/from.txt");
            File newFile = new File("/sdcard/to.txt"); 
           }

     private boolean rename(File from, File to) {
            return from.getParentFile().exists() && from.exists() && from.renameTo(to);
        }
```

It works with android 4.2.2, but with Andoid 9 and 10 it does not work.I have also put `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` and the External Read and Write Permissions into Manifest.xml.

Please help.

Comment: You need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, and you need to ask for it at runtime on Android 6.0 and higher.

Comment: I forgot to say that I have already added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE  permissions.

Comment: Are you requesting them at runtime (`checkSelfPermission()` and `requestPermissions()`)?

Comment: Yes I have already created the runtime permission dialog.

Comment: what is your target SDK and what API level device (or emulator) are you running on

Comment: Is it work on androids from 6 until 9 or 10 ?

Comment: The target SDK is Android 10, API 29, and I am also testing this app on a Android 10 Device

Comment: You are not calling rename(). And runtime permissions?

Comment: I tested it on Android 6, Android 7 and Android 8.It worked on Android 6 and 7 only.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this "error" solved itself. All I did was uninstall and reinstall the app on my Android 10 Device and when the runtime storage permission dialog popped up, I denied the permission first and then I manually allowed it. After this it worked.
I didn't change any of the code above so it might be the runtime permission dialog's fault.

Comment: The changes of your average user Joe to 1) figure this out and 2)go through the process of reinstalling your app instead of looking for an alternative is zero to none. Make sure the issue is reproducible and fix it in a way that doesn't involve the user going through hoops and loops.